# How to run the echo command in Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, echo, paramiko

I need do run the echo command in the python `paramiko.client.SSHClient()` For this can I import any libraries. I tried paramiko.transport also not working.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a SSHClient object use the `exec_command` method to dispatch a command to the client, e.g.

```py
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
... # set client object as needed and connect to SSHClient
command = "ls -l"  # or echo
# execute command and handle output
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
print(stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
print(f"status_code={stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()}")
print(stderr.read().decode("utf-8"))
```